# Python request.get_json() KeyError

Tags: python, html, flask

I've been scratching my head about this for an hour without any solution coming up.
I'm trying to make an AJAX post method as a part of a course and I've tried even copying the instructor code bit by bit and still I'm getting the same error each time.

my Python3 code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://postgres:1999@localhost:5432/crud'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Todo {self.id}{self.description}>'


db.create_all()




@app.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_todo():
    description = request.get_json()['description']
    todo = Todo(description=description)
    db.session.add(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({
        'description': todo.description
    })


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", data=Todo.query.all())
```

my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" id="description" name="description"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Create">
    </form>
    <div id="error" class="hidden">Something went wrong!</div>
    <ul id="todo">
        {% for item in data %}
        <li>{{item.description}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <script>
        let desc =document.getElementById('description').Value;
        document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            fetch('/create',{
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'description': desc
                }),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(function(response){
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (jsonresponse){
                console.log(jsonresponse);
                const item = document.createElement('Li');
                item.innerHTML = jsonresponse['description'];
                document.getElementById('todo').appendChild(item);
                document.getElementById('error').className ='hidden';
            })

            .catch(function (){
                document.getElementById('error').className ='';
            })
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error I'm getting in VS code:

```
[2021-02-09 11:08:56,508] ERROR in app: Exception on /create [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\AmrFa\Desktop\Courses\CRUD\app.py", line 24, in create_todo
    description = request.get_json()['description']
KeyError: 'description'
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2021 11:08:56] "POST /create HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I'm not sure what to do or where to go from here I'm stuck on this.

Comment: Please add `print(request.get_json())` as first line of `create_todo()` and write what is ouptput when you try tu sent your form.

Comment: The only line added output on vs error code is this:

   127.0.0.1 - - [09/Feb/2021 11:30:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - {}

Comment: this mean `{}` i.e. empty dict was received, which explain why key `description` was not found, thus question now why what should be send was not sent.

Comment: fetch 's content-type wasn't working because of marks now that it works it sends 'None'.